# Meta function issue

Tags: post-meta

Taking a clue from older WordPress stock themes I created a meta function to display information about each post.

```
function my_entry_meta() {
// Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'ritualHealing' ) );

// Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
$tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'ritualHealing' ) );

$date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() )
);

$author = sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
    esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'ritualHealing' ), get_the_author() ) ),
    get_the_author()
);

//Translators: 1 is category, 2 is tag, 3 is the date and 4 is the author's name.
?>
 <div class="blog_entry"> 
     <span class="author">Posted by --<a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Posted By">  <?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
     <span class="categories">-- Category --<?php __('%1$s') ?></span> 
     <span class="date">-- <?php __('%3$s') ?> --</span>
     <span class="comments"><a href="single_blog.html" class="normaltip" title="Comments"><?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?></a></span> 
     <span class="tags"><?php __('%2$s') ?></span>
 </div><?php

printf(
    $utility_text,
    $categories_list,
    $tag_list,
    $date,
    $author
);
 }
 endif;
```

For some reason, the category and the date doesn't display. The author name and comment number displays just fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work for a very god reason.

```
<div class="blog_entry"> 
    <span class="author">Posted by --<a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Posted By">  <?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
    <span class="categories">-- Category --<?php __('%1$s') ?></span> 
    <span class="date">-- <?php __('%3$s') ?> --</span>
    <span class="comments"><a href="single_blog.html" class="normaltip" title="Comments"><?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?></a></span> 
    <span class="tags"><?php __('%2$s') ?></span>
</div>
```

This part of your code just doesn't make any sense at all. You try to output categories and dates by printing out format strings and not the values (`<?php __('%1$s') ?>` - where is the value in here? And to be more precise, you even don't print anything in there - `__` function returns it's value and doesn't print anything).

Below you can find correct code

```
function my_entry_meta() {
    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'ritualHealing' ) );

    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'ritualHealing' ) );

    $date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() )
    );

    /* You don't use $author variable anywhere in your ouput (you use the_author tag instead), so it's redundant and should be deleted */
    $author = sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'ritualHealing' ), get_the_author() ) ),
        get_the_author()
    );

    // This comment is wrong - I'm guessing you copied this part of code from a theme that was using sptrinf/printf function to ouput this HTML?
    //Translators: 1 is category, 2 is tag, 3 is the date and 4 is the author's name.
    ?>
    <div class="blog_entry"> 
        <span class="author">Posted by --<a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Posted By">  <?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
        <span class="categories">-- Category --<?php echo $categories_list; ?></span> 
        <span class="date">-- <?php echo $date; ?> --</span>
        <span class="comments"><a href="single_blog.html" class="normaltip" title="Comments"><?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?></a></span> 
        <span class="tags"><?php echo $tag_list; ?></span>
    </div><?php

    /* I'm pretty sure you don't need the printf call from next line */
    printf(
        $utility_text,
        $categories_list,
        $tag_list,
        $date,
        $author
    );
}
```

endif;

Comment: This is working. I took the code from the 2012 theme. I used it the same way in my theme. That is why I thought it would work. All I did was add my html.

Comment: You've also changed the way it generated output - original function used printf with format strings. Your method prints HTML (and inside this HTML you tried to use format strings - it couldn't work like that).